# Pydrake has issue with python 3 point 9

Tags: drake

Is Python3.9 supported?

I got this error with Python3.9:

```
  File "/home/drake/drake/drake-build/install/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydrake/common/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>     from ._module_py import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydrake.common._module_py'
```

There is no "python3.9" folder in .../install/lib.

I am running Ubuntu 18, and I am building Drake from source with latest github commit in master.

EDIT: Can someone explain how exactly Drake sets up pydrake?

It seems it detects the default Python installation somewhere automatically. I tried with a new installation, the default python was 3.8, and I also install:

apt install -y python3.10

Then I followed Drake python setup instructions.

```
git clone https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake.git
mkdir drake-build
cd drake-build
cmake ../drake
make -j
```

Pydrake only became available in 3.8. How to make it available for 3.10?

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Pydrake (1.11.0) is officially supported on Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.8 and Ubuntu 22.04 with Python 3.10 when building from source.  However, we recommend that most users use a binary release, and don't try to rebuild Drake from scratch themselves.

There are precompiled wheels at https://pypi.org/project/drake/ aka `pip install drake`; helpful installation details are at https://drake.mit.edu/pip.html.  The wheels when run on Ubuntu support Python versions 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, or 3.11.

For example:

```
python3 -m venv env
env/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
env/bin/pip install drake
source env/bin/activate
```

For additional details, see https://drake.mit.edu/installation.html for full instructions and supported versions.

The last version of Pydrake to support Ubuntu 18.04 was v1.1.0 (released in March of 2022).  If you need a newer version of Pydrake, you'll need to use a newer version of Ubuntu.

Comment: When you say "not officially supported" does this mean we simply can't build PyDrake for Python3.10 on Ubuntu 20.04? If so, are there any build instructions for that? I've tried `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release  -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.10 -DPython_LIBRARY_RELEASE=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so` but end up getting stuck at `No module named 'numpy'` in the Bazel build. (I can post a separate question if it helps)

Comment: Also, the reason I ask is because I'm able to `pip install drake` in a Python3.10 venv and it works fine for my intents and purposes. So I suppose it must be possible to build.

Comment: As you note, we have wheels for Python 3.10 that should run on any Ubuntu version that's 20.04 or newer. Those are compiled using a magic Dockerfile [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/tools/wheel). Running the vanilla CMake with Python 3.10 on Ubuntu 20.04 will not work, as you note. If you just want to **run** `pydrake`, then use the pip recipe above (or see installation docs for more version / download options).It's not clear to me **why** you are trying to build from source.  If you could explain your overall objective, we can probably give better advice.

Comment: Well my team builds pydrake from source and that's part of the prerequisites for our CMake project. I don't ask questions because I'm the Python guy, but I do try to bind to some of the things in the CMake project. We haven't yet moved to Ubuntu 22.04, and I'd rather not bump back to Python3.8. I hope that's clearer. Also worth noting they build a specific commit hash, whatever suits the team, and they don't necessarily align with official realeases.

Comment: Much clearer, thanks. A good reason to build from source (instead of using whl) is that your team also needs Drake C++ code -- the wheels only have Python.  I've opened a [feature request](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/18719) to explore whether we can get -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE working.  You can subscribe there for updates.

Comment: FYI As of v1.15.0, building Drake from source any Python version can be used.  See https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/19023.